# value of a class member be changed in run time, which kind of error is it?

Tags: c++

My code is like this:

```
class myclass
{
public:
   char someinfo[100];
   void dosomething();
}
void myclass::dosomething()
{
   TRACE("someinfo : %s", someinfo);
   //do something
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myclass* obj = new myclass;
    strncpy(obj->someinfo, "hello,world", 100);
    TRACE("someinfo : %s", obj->someinfo);
    obj->dosomething();
    delete obj;
}
```

The two TRACE's result is like this:

```
someinfo: hello,world
someinfo: ello,world
```

Whick kind error can cause this? It is very strange.

**I have found out why . It should cause this error if you do:**

1. write above code to three files: main.cpp, myclass.h, myclass.cpp
2. make, get main.o, myclass.o; link, get out file test.out
3. edit myclass.h and myclass.cpp, add a bool type member before "char someinfo[100];";
4. just make myclass.o, and link,get a new test.out
5. now,if you execute test.out, this error occur.

Comment: Your first trace in your main function uses the member of the class, and is in the main function undefined. You have to use the pointer `obj->someinfo`.

Comment: That would not even compile. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: The code above just show the expression of error. No matter how to compile

Comment: I have found out why . It should cause this error if you do:
 1. write above code to three files: main.cpp, myclass.h, myclass.cpp
 2. make, get main.o, myclass.o; link, get out file test.out
 3. edit myclass.h and myclass.cpp, add a bool type member before "char someinfo[100];";
 4. just make myclass.o, and link,get a new test.out
 5. now,if you execute test.out, this error occur.

Comment: So you changed your class declaration, but only recompiled part of the code that actually used it?

Comment: I don't even.. why are you doing this to yourself? Pointless dynamic allocation, C-style strings, ..

Comment: There is no need for dynamic allocation here. Among other oddities.

Comment: this type of error is commonly known as a user error. Your main will contain the old definition of the class and the actual mayclass.o will contain the new. the difference between them is that someinfo is offset by one char (bool datatype is typically one char)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have found out why . It should cause this error if you do:
>
> - write above code to three files: main.cpp, myclass.h, myclass.cpp
> - make, get main.o, myclass.o; link, get out file test.out
> - edit myclass.h and myclass.cpp, add a bool type member before "char someinfo[100];";
> - just make myclass.o, and link,get a new test.out
> - now,if you execute test.out, this error occur.

Well, yeah. If you change the layout of a structure common to multiple translation units, but re-compile only one of them, then you have a type discrepancy in your code.

Half your program has one definition, and the other half has another. The C-string is in one place, but half of your program thinks it is found one byte earlier in memory than it really is. No wonder it doesn't work properly!

`[C++11: 3.2/5]` expressly prohibits what you have done.

**Get used to rebuilding *your entire project* when you alter header files.**

Comment: Well, or at least rebuilding the files that depend on the modified header files. A full rebuild is a sure-fire way of doing that, but a blunt one.

Comment: I am ashamed of my Makefile